# mysqlpump --set-gtid-purged=OFF still adds @SESSION.SQL_LOG_BIN=0;

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqldump, gtid

Whenever I add --set-gtid-purged=OFF, **it still adds @@SESSION.SQL_LOG_BIN=0; to the output.**

According to the documentation, shouldn't it get removed?

*--set-gtid-purged=OFF: SET @@SESSION.SQL_LOG_BIN=0; is not added to the output.*

*Dump created by MySQL pump utility, version: 8.0.16, Win64 (x86_64)*

*SET @@SESSION.SQL_LOG_BIN= 0;*

Is this correct behavior for this tool?

Comment: `pump` does not know what you will be doing with the resulting data, so I guess it plays it safe by making sure that non-data things are not replicated.

Comment: Then whats the point of the cmd switch? By adding this it breaks replication if you were to restore a table to a group replicated environment.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug report open for this: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=91915

Describing exactly the issue you are facing.

> mysqlpump with --set-gtid-purged=off, still has "SET @@SESSION.SQL_LOG_BIN=0" in output.

As a "temporary" fix (since the bug report is open since 2018) I simply replaced the line with an empty line.

```
sed -i 's/SET @@SESSION.SQL_LOG_BIN= 0;//' "${DB}.sql"
```

Comment: Crazy - it looks like that bug was reported in 2018. I'm not sure if its been corrected yet. It sure caused me a headache.

Comment: @Watson It's still not fixed since I encountered the bug today on MySQL 8.0.

Comment: 2023 and i was bitten by this, mysql 8.0.35. I went crazy for 3 weeks because i was mounting a innodb cluster and when i restored backup databases go out of sync silently without errors... Guess what? Was that damn SQL_LOG_BIN= 0; and I call mysqlpump with --set-gtid-purged-off... Gosh!